# Csv - Inserting missing rows

Tags: python

I have a huge file, which has some missing rows. The data needs to be rooted at Country.

The input data is like:

```
csv_str = """Type,Country,State,County,City,
1,USA,,,
2,USA,OH,,
3,USA,OH,Franklin,
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Columbus
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Springfield
4,USA,WI,Dane,Madison
"""
```

which needed to be:

```
csv_str = """Type,Country,State,County,City,
1,USA,,,
2,USA,OH,,
3,USA,OH,Franklin,
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Columbus
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Springfield
4,USA,WI,,
4,USA,WI,Dane,
4,USA,WI,Dane,Madison
"""
```

The key as per my logic is `Type` field, where if I cannot find a County (type 3) for a City (type 4), then insert a row with fields upto County.

Same with County.  If I cannot find a State (type 2) for a County (type 3), then insert a row with fields upto State.

With my lack of understanding the facilities in python, I was trying more of a brute-force approach. It is bit problematic as I need lot of iteration over the same file.

I was also tried google-refine, but couldn't get it work. Doing manually is quite error prone.

Any help appreciated.

```
import csv
import io

csv_str = """Type,Country,State,County,City,
1,USA,,,
2,USA,OH,,
3,USA,OH,Franklin,
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Columbus
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Springfield
4,USA,WI,Dane,Madison
"""
found_county =[]
missing_county =[]

def check_missing_county(row):
    found = False
    for elm in found_county:
        if elm.Type == row.Type:
            found = True
    if not found:
        missing_county.append(row)
        print(row)

reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csv_str))
for row in reader:
    check_missing_county(row)
```

Comment: So you just want to generate a list of missing countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've knocked up the following based on my understanding of the question:

```
import csv
import io

csv_str = u"""Type,Country,State,County,City,
1,USA,,,
2,USA,OH,,
3,USA,OH,Franklin,
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Columbus
4,USA,OH,Franklin,Springfield
4,USA,WI,Dane,Madison
"""

counties = []
states = []


def handle_missing_data(row):
    try:
        rtype = int(row[0])
    except ValueError:
        return []

    rtype = row[0]
    country = row[1]
    state = row[2]
    county = row[3]

    rows = []
    # if a state is present and it hasn't a row of it's own
    if state and state not in states:
        rows.append([rtype, country, state, '', ''])
        states.append(state)

    # if a county is present and it hasn't a row of it's own
    if county and county not in counties:
        rows.append([rtype, country, state, county, ''])
        counties.append(county)

    # if the row hasn't already been added add it now
    if row not in rows:
        rows.append(row)

    return rows

csvf = io.StringIO(csv_str)
reader = csv.reader(csvf)
for row in reader:
    new_rows = handle_missing_data(row)
    for new_row in new_rows:
        print new_row
```